# Define cellsize from spsample in meters

Tags: shapefile, r, grids-graticules, sp

I use a shapefile to create a regular grid using `spsample`, from `sp` package.

Two problems here: (1) I would like to define the size of my grid cells in meters, but I've checked the documentation of `sp` and it is not clear what is the default unit of measure ; (2) This code works to create `hexagonal` grid but I can't make this work to create a `regular` grid. Any ideas?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
# load libraries    
  library(sp)
  library(rgdal)
```

**Download a shapefile**

```
URL <- "ftp://dnrftp.dnr.ne.gov/pub/data/state/Legislative2010UTM.zip"
fil <- basename(URL)
if (!file.exists(fil)) download.file(URL, fil)

# unzip & get list of files
fils <- unzip(fil)

# find the shapefile in it
shp <- grep("shp$", fils, value=TRUE)

# get the first layer from it
lay <- ogrListLayers(shp)[1]

# read in the shapefile
leg <- readOGR(shp, lay)

plot(leg)
```

[image]

### Define size of hexagon bins

```
HexPts <-spsample(leg,type="hexagonal", offset=c(0,0), cellsize=100000)

# Create hexagon grid as spatial polygons
HexPols <- HexPoints2SpatialPolygons(HexPts)


plot(HexPols, add=T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `spsample` with `cellsize`:

```
pts = spsample(leg, cellsize=c(10000,10000), type="regular")
plot(leg)
points(pts)
```

check the coordinate spacing:

```
> coordinates(pts)[1:10,]
       x1      x2
17 244356 4437161
18 254356 4437161
19 264356 4437161
```

you see the x coordinate going by 10,000 (and if you look later on you'll see the y coordinate does too)

Comment: Thanks Barry. Do you what is the default unit of measure for the cell size?  and is it possible to define the cell size in meters?

Comment: Its whatever the units of the map projection of your `leg` object is. And in this case, metres: `proj4string(leg)` gives: `"+proj=utm +zone=14 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0""+proj=utm +zone=14 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"` - see `"+units=m"` there?